# How to login and get root desktop environment in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

how do i login with root account and get root desktop environment in ubuntu 14.10

Pls advise .

Reg,
Sufi

Comment: Why do you need that? Can't you just perform root operations with `sudo`?

Comment: yes i am not able to set permissions using gui on users folders i am learning linux so that it is very hard to set permission using terminal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enter your password to gain root access

`sudo -i`

`passwd`

enter password for root login

log out and login with root as username and password

or else

if you need to browse your files only, then

`gksudo nautilus`

**I don't know why you need this. It is strictly discouraged to activate a root account.**

Answer (score -1):

in linux you don't need to use root but if it's just for a file press alt+F2 and type gksu nautilus, enter your password and now you can browse your files as root